# No text processed after cover page in ConTeXt

Tags: context, covers

I'm trying to insert a pdf as a cover page in a ConTeXt document. I've read [Including pages from PDF documents](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Including_pages_from_PDF_documents) and have come up with the following MWE,

```
\startTEXpage
  \externalfigure[cover][width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]
\stopTEXpage

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Background}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

The problem is that nothing after the cover page gets processed at all and thus I end up with a 1 page pdf as output. The result is the same even if the external figure is a JPG image file instead of PDF.

Comment: You have to add `\starttext` at the begin of your document and `\stoptext` at the end. When you use `\startTEXpage` without a preceding `\starttext` the document ends with the next `\stopTEXpage` and everything after it is ignored.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Thanks. Can you please add it as an answer so that I may accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a document contain a `\startTEXpage` command without a previous `\starttext` (or `\startcomponent` etc.) the following `\stopTEXpage` marks the end of the document and everything after it is ignored.